# Formatting a text in a button

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm designing a jquery mobile app which i will compile with cordova. I'm using the share plugin so i can invite people to download the app. Onclick of the button it opens up the share window then you select the app you wish to share the message with. i want to format the text which will be sent in the button my can't find my way through. I want to add some paragraphs and also make some bold.

```
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('<p>Hey</p> follow this link and download this <strong>app</strong>')">Download app</button>
```

Comment: What is the result? Do you see any text in the button?

Comment: it prints out exactly the text without formatting it with the paragraph and bold

Comment: What `window.plugins.socialsharing.share` function looks like? Probably it uses `textContent` or similar when changing the text in the button. About [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) MDN says "Permitted content: [Phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content)". The list doesn't contain `<p>` though.